# How do I use reject properly in this setTimeout using promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

AsyncTimeout simply wraps setTimeout in a promise so that it can be used in promise chains.  However I did not see a good place to implement the `reject()`

```
function asyncTimeout(time, callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const results = callback();
      resolve(results);
    }, time );
  });
}

asyncTimeout(1000, (test) => {
  console.log('resloved');
}).then(()=>{
  console.log('now what')
});
```

Comment: What do you mean *"implement the `reject()`"*? Under what circumstances should the promise be rejected and go to a catch instead of the then? We can't tell you that.

Comment: `reject` is already implemented for you. You can call it wherever you like based on your logic since you're the program author. Under what condition do you want to reject the promise?

Comment: Wrap your callback inside a try catch, and reject there..eg.. `try { const results = callback() } catch(e) { reject (e) }`

Comment: Why do you need a callback at all? `asyncTimeout(1000).then(...).then(...)` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your `callback()` call in a `try`/`catch` block and call `reject(err)` in case of an exception:

```
function asyncTimeout(time, callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      try {
        const results = callback();
        resolve(results);
      } catch(err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    }, time );
  });
}
```

However the proper solution is to not pass a callback to `asyncTimeout` at all - just use the returned promise and its `then` method! The promise will always be fulfilled, you don't need to use `reject`:

```
function asyncTimeout(time, callback) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  });
}

asyncTimeout(1000).then(() => {
  console.log('resolved');
  throw new Error('oops');
  console.log('now what');
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('handled', err);
});
```

Comment: Sure we can assume setTimeout does not throw an error or we could put it in a try catch block just to be consistent.  Either way would be fine I take it?

Comment: Yes, `setTimeout` does not throw any error afaik (maybe when you exhaust timer ids?), but even if it did then the `new Promise` constructor would already handle synchronous exceptions from the executor callback and reject the promise.